# Shoucast/ICECast stream conversion from MP3 to HE-AAC Stream

Tags: streaming, music, internet-radio, shoutcast

I have a stream that's being received in MP3 and I'd like to convert it to another stream that will feed another instance of Shoutcast/ICEcast in audio/aacp format.

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [EzStream](http://www.icecast.org/ezstream.php).

I have been playing with this a while ago to [play MP3 files to an Icecast stream](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/streaming-your-mp3-collection-through-an-icecast-server-using-ezstream/), but EZstream can also do stream-to-stream conversions.

Another option would be to use the BASS library to fetch an MP3 stream and push it to an AACP stream.

In fact I'm working on an app that does a similar thing.

If EzStream does not work for you, then please remind me in the holiday season, and I'll try to come up with something in BASS.

--jeroen